# How to fix resharper line wrapping indents

Tags: resharper

Resharper seems to have gone berserk and is wrapping lines without an indent, i.e. they are hugging the margin. This uglyness makes me rip my shirt off and go wild.

```
    else
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "PRIORITY",
polcvgSetCollection.Max(p => p.PRIORITY) + 1);                
                }
```

See the line popping out of the brace. It's disgusting.

Can anyone help fix this? I've looked through the settings for Resharper->Options->Line Breaks and can't find which one will fix it. Cheers.

Comment: What happens when you a ctrl+k+d? Or a resharper code cleanup? You might have to reinstall resharper.

Comment: ctrl+k+d does nothing. i'll have to try reinstalling this weekend and let you know what happens. cheers iain

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this possibly Visual Studio's Word Wrap rather than a Resharper setting?  Try turning VS's wrapping off with:

Tools - Options - Text Editor - All Languages - Word Wrap

Comment: a thousand thankyous. my lines are now formattign nicely. i've no idea how that setting became enabled, but it is no more.

Comment: It's also under: Edit - Advanced - Word Wrap (Ctrl+E, W). It's very easy to hit that key combination by mistake. Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 11):

For Resharper 8.2

> Resharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line
>   Breaks and Wrapping > uncheck Wrap long lines

Resharper Options
[image: Resharper Options]

Answer (score 7):

Look at Resharper->Options->C#->Formating Style->Other->Indentation.

This is maybe the option you are looking for.